# Why appear in console this error of ionic template?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an ionic list that is filled with an ngfor. The list fills without problem, it locks up a bit, however in the console a syntax error appears for one of the ngfor tags.

My Ionic info is:
ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.12.0 
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

This is the code of my template:

```
<ion-content padding>
  Tap sobre el producto para añadirlo a favoritos.
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let task of tasks; let i = index">
      <ion-item (click)="gofav(task.id)">
        <ion-avatar item-start>
          <img src="{{ task.foto }}">
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2 style="padding: 15px 15px;"> {{ task.nombre }}
          <ion-icon *ngIf="task.favs == 1" name="star"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon *ngIf="task.favs == 0" name="star-outline"></ion-icon>
        </h2>
        <p>{{ task.presentacion | presentacion }}</p>
        <h1 item-end>{{ task.precio }}</h1>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item-options>
        <button ion-button color="primary" icon-start (click)="deleteproduct(task.id)">
          <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
          Borrar
        </button>
        <button ion-button color="light" icon-start (click)="gotomodproduct(task.id)">
          <ion-icon name="keypad"></ion-icon>
          Modificar
        </button>
      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
  <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="Cargando más productos..."></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

The error that comes up in console is this:

[image: console error]

[image: console error 2]

This is the example of the data in a "task" object.

```
{ 
  brand: 0,
  catg: "116",
  codigo: "7861006000202",
  favs: 1,
  foto: "file:///data/data/io.ionic.starter/files/taoEhpeVIJ.jpg",
  id: 24,
  iddb: 313,
  impor: 0,
  nombre: "Paños Multiusos Super Absorbentes",
  origfrm: 1,
  precio: "300,00",
  presentacion: "2 Unidades"
}
```

Comment: what's on line 27?

Comment: @kkesley https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti7rq.png

Comment: @Alor what is task.nombre?

Comment: what format your “foto” is in ? base64 image?

Comment: can you share example of data in your task object?

Comment: @AbdulAzeem It's a string

Comment: @SergeyRudenko No, it's JPG

Comment: @SergeyRudenko 
I edited my question and added an example of the data in a "task" object.